# How can I transfer data from Google CloudPlatform NodeJS app to BigQuery?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have currently set up a NodeJS "server" on GoogleCloud Platform server where I am listening and receiving POST HTTP calls.
The body of each call contains a JSON that I would like to parse and transfer to Google BigQuery.
For now, this is the code I've created to receive the POST request:

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const messages = [];

async function startServer() {

  const app = express();
  app.use(express.json());

  app.post("/receive2", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: req.body });
    //Here I should manager the json contained in req.body
  });

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  logger.info({ PORT }, "bonjour");

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
  });

}

startServer();
```

The JSON is something similar to: https://gist.github.com/philipgiuliani/b63b22309d04048f0827

Yes, I am trying to save the receipts from In-App-Purchases made in my iOS app.

Can someone provide me a way to transfer the data of those receipts that I'm receiving to a BigQuery Table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NodeJS to append your csv data to a existing table or create a new table. I would recommend using Google Cloud Storage as a intermediate where you store the csv and simply point bigquery to the csv file which it should load. However you could also stream the data.

Stream:

```js
let _count = await _BigQuery_
                    .dataset('dataset_name')
                    .table('table_name')
                    .query(`SELECT count(*) from table_name`)
                    .catch(e => console.error(e))
if (_count[0][0].count > 0)
   console.log('no data')
```

Google Cloud Storage
Stream:

```js
const gcs_file = Storage.file(gcs_path)
const gcs_write_stream = gcs_file.createWriteStream()
stream_from_csv_file
   .on('error', (error) => {
        gcs_write_stream.close()
   })
   .on('data', data => {
        gcs_write_stream.write(row + '\r\n')
   })
   .on('end', function () {
        gcs_write_stream.end();
        loadFileToBigquery();
   });

async function loadFIleToBigQuery(){
   
   await _BigQuery_
          .etl
          .table('current_geoms_raw')
          .load(gcs_file , {
                  sourceFormat: 'CSV',
                  skipLeadingRows: 1, // if headers are in csv
                  autodetect: false, // sometimes fails if true
                  location: 'US',
          })
          .catch(e => console.error(e))
}
```